# Joining DataFrame with multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm taking a standard data frame and creating various sub-set data frames of summary data. These subsets will all be at double indexed with the first index being the same. I'm being asked to get all my summary data together (They want to create a single JSON for all summary data). I thought combining the data frames would be the easiest solution, but I'm having trouble.

Standard Dataframe example: df

```
   ID   DEPT   STATUS    TYPE
0  100  5001   Active      E
1  101  5001   Active      M
2  101  5001   Active      M
3  102  5005   Expired     E
4  107  5001   Inactive    M
5  110  5002   Inactive    E
6  110  5002   Inactive    E
```

I then create my summary data and rename the column:

```
status_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['DEPT','STATUS'])['ID'].nunique())

status_df.columns = ['Count_Status']
```

---

```
               Count_Status
DEP  STATUS  
5001 Active    2
     Inactive  1 
5002 Inactive  1
5005 Expired   1
```

and again for the other column:

```
type_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['DEPT','TYPE'])['ID'].nunique())

type_df.columns = ['Count_Type']
```

---

```
              Count_Type
DEP  TYPE
5001 E        1
     M        2 
5002 E        1
5005 E        1
```

What I would like to create:

```
                     Count_Status   Count_Type
DEP  
     STATUS    TYPE
5001 Active          2              NaN
     Inactive        1              NaN
               E     NaN            1
               M     NaN            2
5002 Inactive        1              NaN
               E     NaN            1
5005 Expried         1              NaN
               E     NaN            1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, using `pd.concat` and `set_index`:

```
d1 = (df.groupby(['DEPT','STATUS'])['ID'].nunique()
        .rename('Count Status')
        .reset_index(level=1))

d2 = (df.groupby(['DEPT','TYPE'])['ID'].nunique()
        .rename('Count Type')
        .reset_index(level=1))

df_out = (pd.concat([d1, d2], sort=False)
            .set_index(['STATUS','TYPE'], append=True)
            .sort_index())
df_out
```

Output:

```
                    Count Status  Count Type
DEPT STATUS   TYPE                          
5001 Active   NaN            2.0         NaN
     Inactive NaN            1.0         NaN
     NaN      E              NaN         1.0
              M              NaN         2.0
5002 Inactive NaN            1.0         NaN
     NaN      E              NaN         1.0
5005 Expired  NaN            1.0         NaN
     NaN      E              NaN         1.0
```

Comment: Adding ".reset_index(level=1)" to my d1 and d2 caused the following error: ValueError: DataFrame index  must be unique for orient='columns'.

Comment: Did you do the rename?

Comment: Yes. BTW, thanks for that tip. Much nicer than doing it in two lines.

Comment: Hrm.. you are copying this code as is?  What version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your complete dataset online so I can do some testing with the actual data generating the error?

Comment: Ok, I see why I was getting the error, I left in a spot check trying to make d1 and d2 into json's before continuing. I took that out and the ", sort=False" and got your output. This may work for me. I have to test how we will be using the json output from this dataframe. Thank you!